# Unable to return value from Struct to View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

So I'll keep it simple. I've seen questions with similar error.

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

But I already defined `medicalContent` as a string so I don't know what's goin wrong. I just wish to pass the return `medicalContent` string from the struct to the `textEditor` in the view. Any input shall be appreciated!

Code:

```
struct MedicalEdit: View {


@State var medicalContent: String = ""

init(){
    fetchCalmStuff()
}

func fetchCalmStuff(){
        
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        
        let ref = db.collection("list").document(uid).collection("notes")
                 
             ref.document("medical").setData(["content":"medical content","identity":"medical" ])
        
        
        db.collection("userslist").document(uid).collection("Themes").whereField("identity", isEqualTo: "medical")
            .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let medicalContent = data["content"] as! String ?? ""
                       print(medicalContent)
                        return medicalContent // this is where I get error // that Unexpected non-void return value in void function.
                          
                        
                    }
                }
        }
}

var body: some View {
    



    TextEditor(text: $medicalContent)

}

}
```

EDIT: Also how come it can print `medicalContent` but cannot return it? I'm kinda confused.

Comment: `getDocuments` is an asynchronous function. At the time you try to return, you're in a callback function, which you cannot return from. Instead, set a `@State` variable based on `medicalContent`

Comment: @jnpdx oh wait hold on so declaring `medicalContent` as a State Variable on top doesn't help? Unless I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: You're *redeclaring* it when you say `let medicalContent`. You should instead do `self.medicalContent = data["content"] as! String ?? ""` and *not* `return`

Comment: @jnpdx Okay I think that technically makes sense. I just tried using `self.medicalContent = data["content"] as! String ?? ""` instead of ` let medicalContent = data["content"] as! String ?? ""` but I'm still getting the same error. Pardon my ignorance I'm still learning!

Comment: okay my bad. I just removed the 'return' call and used the self method. Now I'm not even getting the content being printed to console. Kinda confused

Comment: That makes sense, actually -- `@State` doesn't update immediately.

Comment: So what do you think is going wrong? I can't directly see what's wrong. Again, I'm still leaning everyday so sorry for my confusion

Comment: I don't necessarily think anything *is* wrong. What happens if you `print(data)`?

Comment: I get `["identity": medical, "content": medical content]' if I do `print[data]`

Comment: Sounds like `content` isn't a `String`? Maybe? Weird that there isn't quotes around it. What does your Firebase entry look like?

Comment: @jnpdx Firebase data does indeed say that content is a `(string)` I just checked.

Comment: Okay, then it sounds like everything is working. Are you not getting the text in the `TextEditor`?

Comment: Also also FYI if I try to print ` print(medicalContent)` in inside `var body: some View ` I get empty in console. By empty I mean nothing at all. (not the word 'empty')

Comment: Yeah I 'm not getting text in TExtEditor at all

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `fetchCalmStuff()` in `init`. What happens if you call it in `onAppear`?

Comment: Yeah that's weird that I don't get anything when I `print(medicalContent)` but I get `["identity": medical, "content": medical content]'` if I do `print[data]`

Comment: Okay the app breaks if I call the `fetch` command as a `onAppear` inside `var body: some View  ` as Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d1dffc8)

Comment: "Yeah that's weird that I don't get anything when" -- already addressed that above. `@State` doesn't get set immediately. That's why I suggested `print(data)`, which does show the value. Not sure about the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` without being able to run it and test it myself. You could try it inside `.task { }` instead of `onAppear`

Comment: Okay I was able to achieve this using `@ObservableObject` and `@Published Property`. However, like you said, my text editor doesn't immediately update if the content value is changed. Do you know if there's any workaround this property of the `@State var` nature?

Comment: The update to the text editor should be on the next run loop after setting the published property — basically instantaneous

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more what you mean by this? I'm a little confused. Are you saying I need to declare the texteditor value after declaring the Published variable?

Comment: I don't know what that means. I'm saying that everything *looks* like it should work. You're saying that your text editor doesn't immediately update, but I can't see any code that would make this not happen. How long is the update taking?

Comment: I have to go back to the previous view and open the texteditor view in order to see the update

Comment: Okay. Can you update your question to your current code with the ObservableObject and Published property?